# Function to create N arrays from one data group

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am new in PL/pgsql and I would like to create a new Function.

In my case I have this table:

```
Column 1: VARIABLE = 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
Column 2: VALUE = 20 20 20 20 180 180 180 180 180 180
Column3: STRETCH = 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

And I would like to do a function to create N arrays from field VALUE where the STRETCH is different, for example:

```
Array 1: 20,20,20,20,180,180,
Array 2: 180,180,180,180,
```

How can I do it?

Comment: the select to do that should be "select array_agg(VALUE) from t group by STRETCH". I think you can work out the function yourself?

Comment: Please provide a proper table definition (like `\d tbl` in psql would give you), your version of Postgres. And "different" from what?

Comment: The problem is that stackoverflow don´t let me attach a image capture from my table. Anyway my columns are VARIABLE(integer), VALUE(real) and STRETCH(integer). My version Postgresql is 9.1.

I would like as result few arrays from the column VALUE where the condition is the STRETCH value. In the above example while the value of STRETCH is '1' I get all values from VALUE and I create a array1, then while the value is '2' I get all values from column VALUE and I create another array, array2.

I want to do this because then I would like get all my arrays and calculate the mean value each.

Comment: if you need the mean for each STREACH what's wrong with a simple "select STRETCH, avg(VALUE) from t group by STRETCH" ???

Comment: @Acicate: Please use "edit" left under your question to update it with basic information. Don't squeeze that into comments. Table definitions should never be provided as images. We can't copy / paste images to work with them. Also, you can use SQLfiddle to provide a test case. Random example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/80d87/2

Answer (score 1):

This would be a useful way to provide a test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (variable int, value real, stretch int);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (2, 20, 1)
 ,(2, 20, 1)
 ,(2, 20, 1)
 ,(2, 20, 1)
 ,(2, 180, 1)
 ,(2, 180, 1)
 ,(2, 180, 2)
 ,(2, 180, 2)
 ,(2, 180, 2)
 ,(2, 180, 2);
```

#### What you asked

```
SELECT variable, stretch, array_agg(value) AS val_arr
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

#### What you seem to need

> I want to do this because then I would like get all my arrays and
>   calculate the mean value each.

```
SELECT variable, stretch, avg(value) AS val_avg
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fc0fa/3)

[Aggregate functions in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

[Try a search to find plenty of code examples how to create a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20create%20function)